# Framework for editing, uploading, saving Excel in React

Tags: javascript, microsoft-excel, react

I'm using React and I need a library and by using it I want to upload an excel from the computer (I'm doing it with react-dropzone), edit it in the browser and can save the edited version to the computer or to a remote computer(cloud) in excel format.

Which library provides those capabilities? Right now, I don't need macro functionalities but it might be a good idea to support macros.

I have looked at [pure javascript sheetjs](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx), [handsontable](https://handsontable.com/), and Google API.

I liked handsontable however, there is little documentation about React and to edit a document and preserve styles etc. I need to write a lot of code and search for the documentation.

Google API is not what I want. Because I don't want to store uploaded documents in the Google and send to the user a google link.

Comment: As far as I know, nothing exists with this functionality, you will probably need to program it. Have you looked into https://github.com/plotly/react-pivottable ? I've used it to display table data within minutes of putting up a react app.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that @CalebJay